# Let $v,w \in R^n$ with $||u||=||w||=1$. Prove that there exists orthogonal matrix $A$ such that $Av=w$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, orthogonal-matrices

> Let $v,w \in \mathbb R^n$ with $\|u\|=\|w\|=1$. Prove that there exists
>   orthogonal matrix $A$ such that $Av=w$. Also prove that $A$ can be
>   chosen such that $\det(A)=1$

Here, $u\neq 0$ and $w\neq 0$ so I can extend these to get

$B_1 = \{u,x2,x3\dots x_n\}$ and $B_2=\{w,y2\dots y_n\}$ both orthonormal basis of $R^n$

and define $T:R^n \to R^n $ as $T(u)=w$ and $T(x_i)=y_i \;\; \forall i\leq i \leq n$

here will $A=[T]_{B_1}^{B2}$ satisfy the given conditions?

I can't think of another way to solve this. please help

Comment: Sometimes you use $u$, sometimes you use $v$. Please, fix this.

Comment: I suppose we should specify that $n \geq 2$.  In the $n = 1$ case, there is no $A$ with positive determinant satisfying $A(1) = -1$.

Comment: Also, the matrix $A$ you want is really the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis.  The matrix of $T$ relative to $B_1$ and $B_2$ is simply the identity matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes I agree,$[T]_{B_1}^{B_2}$ is simply the identity matrix, how do I show matrix of $T$ relative to standard basis satisfies these conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need no other way! That works. The matrix of a linear map $f$ with respect to two orthonormal bases is orthogonal if and only if, if $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is the first basis, then $\{f(v_1),\ldots,f(v_n)\}$ is an orthonormal basis too. In order to have determinant $1$, you may have to change the sign of the image of one of the vectors.

Comment: I think $A=[T]_{B_1}^{B} = [w, y_2,\ldots, y_n]$, where $B$ is standard basis, is the matrix that I'm looking for. Do you agree?

Comment: Since the standard basis is an orthogonal basis, that would work, yes.

Comment: The argument to show that this $A=[w,y_2\ldots, y_n]$ is orthogonal would be to say that it's column vectors form an orthonormal set and so $A$ is orthogonal.

Since $A$ is orthogonal, $det(A)=\pm 1$. So to get $A$ with determinant $1$, I can always multiply one of the column vectors with $-1$ to get desired $A$. Is this argument correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct, unless you multiply the first column by $-1$. Any other column will do.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your result will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct. To get  determinant $1$ just note that if you replace $y_n$ by $-y_n$ (keeping everything else fixed) then determinant of the matrix becomes the negative of the old one. Hence we can get $A$ with $det(A)=1$.

The determinant of a real orthogonal matrix is $+1$ or $-1$.